# Using String Parameters for Linux Desktopbus Interprocess Communication in Python

Tags: python, linux, ipc

I am currently struggling to call a desktopbus method with string parameters within python. I try this using the dbus-python lib (https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/ --> I am open for other libs too). I have no issue calling methods that do not use any parameter or pure integer parameters like this:

```
from gi.repository import GLib
import sys
import dbus
import dbus.service
import dbus.mainloop.glib
from threading import Thread


class DesktopBus:

   def __init__(self, ip, port):
       self.ip = ip
       self.port = port
       dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
       self.proxy = {}
       self.properties_manager = {}
       self.thread = None
       self.mainLoop = GLib.MainLoop()

   def call_method(self, str_interface_name, str_method_name, param_list):
       """
       in:
       str_interface_name: eg. "com.MyService"
       str_method_name: Method name as string.
       param_list as list: eg [] or [1,2,3]
       """
       params = ""
       for i in param_list:
           params += str(i) + ","
       return eval('self.properties_manager["' + str_interface_name + '"].' + str_method_name + '(' +
                   params + 'dbus_interface="' + str_interface_name + '")')

db = DesktopBus("192.168.0.2", "50000")
db.openInterface("SomeService")
db.call_method("SomeService", "function", [1, 2, 3])
```

The code works with integer parameters. However with strings it fails (e. g. db.call_method("SomeService", "function", ["a", "b"]). Can anyone please help me :)

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text(not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you define `def call_method` but later you use `callMethod` - it is two different names.

Comment: you could first assing function to variable - ie. `cmd` - and use `print(cmd)` before `eval(cmd)`. As for me problem is that strings `"a"`, `"b"` may need extra `" "` - if you don't use it then it may treat `a`, `b` as names of variables, not string. You may use `" "` inside `' '` - `['"a"', '"b"']`

Comment: @furas sry issue whilst making the code annonymous.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show full error message so I can only guess.

---

I can't run it but as for me problem is that it will put `["a", "b"]` in string as `(a, b, ...)` and `eval()` will treat `a`, `b` as variables.

You may have to put every string in extenal `' '` to keep `" "` as part of text - `['"a"', '"b"']`

```
db.callmethod("SomeService", "function", ['"a"', '"b"'])
```

See

```
param_list = ["a", "b"]

params = ""
for i in param_list:
    params += str(i) + ","

print(params)
```

gives string:

```
a,b,
```

but

```
param_list = ['"a"', '"b"']

params = ""
for i in param_list:
    params += str(i) + ","

print(params)
```

gives string which you need:

```
"a","b",
```

---

But frankly you could try to do it without `eval()` and then it wouldn't need extra `' '` because it will not convert it all to string.

```
def call_method(self, str_interface_name, str_method_name, param_list):

    interface = self.properties_manager[str_interface_name]

    method = getattr(interface, str_method_name)

    result = method(*params_list, dbus_interface=str_interface_name)

    return result
```

Comment: I investigated the issue deeper. The lib does not accept sting parameters (for some magic reason). A workarround is to use the linux tool busctl and just use os.system with the corresponding command. Anyway thanks for the help.